# Unable to convert a list into a dataframe. Keep getting the error "ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 4, 5)"

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have to 2 dfs:

**dfMiss:**

[image]

and

**dfSuper:**

[image]

I need to create a final output that summarises the data in the 2 tables which I am able to do shown in the code below:

```
dfCity = dfSuper \
    .groupby(by='City').count() \
    .drop(columns='Superhero ID') \
    .rename(columns={'Superhero': 'Total count'})

print("This is the df city : ")
print(dfCity)



## Convert column MissionEndDate to DateTime format
for df in dfMiss:
    # Dates are interpreted as MM/dd/yyyy by default, dayfirst=False
    df['Mission End date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Mission End date'], dayfirst=True)

    # Get Year and Quarter, given Q1 2020 starts in April
    date = df['Mission End date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)
    df['Mission End quarter'] = date.dt.year.astype(str) + ' Q' + date.dt.quarter.astype(str)

## Get no. Superheros working per City per Quarter
dfCount = []

for dfM in dfMiss:
    # Merge DataFrames
    df = dfSuper.merge(dfM, left_on='Superhero ID', right_on='SID')

 
    df = df.pivot_table(index=['City', 'Superhero'], columns='Mission End quarter', aggfunc='nunique')

    # Get the first group (all the groups have the same values)
    df = df[df.columns[0][0]]

    # Group the values by City (effectively "collapsing" the 'Superhero' column)
    df = df.groupby(by=['City']).count()

    dfCount += [df]

## Get no. Superheros available per City per Quarter
dfFree = []

for dfC in dfCount:

    # Merge DataFrames
    df = dfCity.merge(right=dfC, on='City', how='outer').fillna(0)  # convert NaN values to 0

    # Subtract no. working superheros from total no. superheros per city
    for col in df.columns[1:]:
        df[col] = df['Total count'] - df[col]
    dfFree += [df.astype(int)]

    print(dfFree)
dfResult = pd.DataFrame(dfFree)
```

The problem is when I try to convert DfFree into a dataframe I get the error:

**"ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 4, 5) "**

The line that raises the error is

```
dfResult = pd.DataFrame(dfFree)
```

Anyone have any idea what this means and how I can convert the list into a df?

Thanks :)

Comment: What code actually raises the error?

Comment: The final line:  dfResult = pd.DataFrame(dfFree)

Comment: Based on the shape, pass in `dfFree[0]`

Comment: Wow thanks Mad Physicist that worked! Why did that work?!

Comment: Error says your shape has three dimensions, with the first one being one. If you take the first element along the first dimension, you get the remainder as a 2D array

Comment: As to how that ends up happening, I'll look at it later and draft an answer

Answer (score 1):

separate your code using SOLID.  separation of concerns.  It is not easy to read

```
 sid=[665544,665544,2121,665544,212121,123456,666666]
 mission_end_date=["10/10/2020", "03/03/2021", "02/02/2021", "05/12/2020", "15/07/2021", "03/06/2021", "12/10/2020"]

 superherod_sid=[212121,364331,678523,432432,665544,123456,555555,666666,432432]
 hero=["Spiderman","Ironman","Batman","Dr. Strange","Thor","Superman","Nightwing","Loki","Wolverine"]
 city=["New York","New York","Gotham","New York","Asgard","Metropolis","Gotham","Asgard","New York"]

 df_mission=pd.DataFrame({'sid':sid,'mission_end_date':mission_end_date})
 df_super=pd.DataFrame({'sid':superherod_sid,'hero':hero, 'city':city})

 df=df_super.merge(df_mission,on="sid", how="left")
 df['mission_end_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['mission_end_date'])
 df['mission_end_date_quarter']=df['mission_end_date'].dt.quarter
 df['mission_end_date_year']=df['mission_end_date'].dt.year
 print(df.head(20))

 pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['city', 'hero'], columns='mission_end_date_quarter',  aggfunc='nunique').fillna(0)
 print(pivot.head())
```